# View: Recent posts all users

Tags: views

I'm working on drupal 7 with Views 3.8. I'm trying to make a view with one post(most recent one) of all users of my site. I found out via this forum I can make a view based on all users. I then add a relationship called User: Representative node. And I choose to sort on [post date].

Now this should work right? But the view doesn't show the most recent post but it shows the oldest post. I tried change descending to ascending or change the sorting to [NID] or [post updated] but nothing seems to work. What can I do?

If it's usefull here's my view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'recent';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Recent';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Recent';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: User: Representative node */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_representative']['id'] = 'uid_representative';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_representative']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_representative']['field'] = 'uid_representative';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_representative']['subquery_sort'] = 'node.created';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_representative']['subquery_view'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_representative']['subquery_namespace'] = '';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'uid_representative';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'recent';
$translatables['recent'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Recent'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('Representative node'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view,

- To sort based on Posted Date of content, then You should adding a **Sort Criteria:** `Content: Post date` as *Descending*
- To sort based on Updated Date of content, then You should adding a **Sort Criteria:** `Content: Update date` as *Descending*

Comment: Thanks for answering, but as said in my post it doesn't matter if I use Ascending or Descending or a different sort method. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance